# JDBC Custom TypeMapping Order Issue

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, spring-jdbc

Hi I use springjdbc to call storedprocedure in oracle.I have storedprocedure and my output property custom udt object.In my java code ,I want to get this type as java class for this I create my custom class and  implements SQLData and it works.But my problem is ,if the udt property order change in database 
like at first case city is my number 3 parameter in udt and state is number 4.And my java class is at same order but I switch only parameter order and that time Values set wrong(city value to state and state value to city set)
Is there way to control this order confusion.

```
>  CREATE TYPE ADDRESS   (
    >     NUM INTEGER, (1)
    >     STREET VARCHAR(40),(2)
    >     CITY VARCHAR(40),(3)
    >     STATE VARCHAR(2),(4)
    >   



ZIP CHAR(5) (5)  );


public class Address implements SQLData {
    public int num;
    public String street;
    public String city;
    public String state;
    public String zip;
    private String sql_type;

public String getSQLTypeName() {
    return sql_type;
}

public void readSQL(SQLInput stream, String type)
    throws SQLException {
    sql_type = type;
    num = stream.readInt();
    street = stream.readString();
    city = stream.readString();
    state = stream.readString();
    zip = stream.readString();
}

public void writeSQL(SQLOutput stream)
    throws SQLException {
    stream.writeInt(num);
    stream.writeString(street);
    stream.writeString(city);
    stream.writeString(state);
    stream.writeString(zip);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Not Directly but with ORAData, ORADataFactory there is a way.With ORAData Create method we can access type metadata information to help structdescriptor.getMetaData() function.Then we can combine with values

```
public ORAData create(Datum datum, int i) throws SQLException

 StructDescriptor sd = StructDescriptor.createDescriptor("TYPENAME", c);

        int ColumnCount = sd.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
        for (int columCounter = 1; columCounter <= ColumnCount; columCounter++) {
            String ColumnName = sd.getMetaData().getColumnName(columCounter);
```